# How to model object creation in a sequence diagram with Papyrus

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, papyrus

I'm creating a sequence diagram in Papyrus. I want to model the creation of an object at runtime using a create message. There is a "Message Create" in Papyrus, but I don't know how to use it. Neither can I find any documenation about it. Can someone explain it to me or point me to a proper documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two lifelines and them create a "MessageCreate" from the "line of the first Lifeline to the "head" of the second one. Please see my example below.[image]

Comment: Ok, that's what I was trying to do. Is there any condition under which no message is created? Or is there any log where I can see a reason for this to fail?

Comment: Actually you are not showing a normal message but a Create message. So it should not be labeled with "Message". Eventually use the class name to indicate instance creation.

Comment: It's working now. For some reason it didn't work with the lifeline I created. I started a new diagram and it's working now. Maybe a bug.